# App em react native não atualiza

Tags: react-native

Olá.

Estou fazendo o app, porém a aplicação não atualiza quando modifico o código. Só fica na tela padrão de teste... Com a mensagem de pressionar o "R" duas vezes.
Estou usando o celular para executar a aplicação.

Durante a compilação aparece essa mensagem: Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Acredito que o problema possa ser esse, já pesquisei, porém ainda não encontrei uma solução.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer uma **Tour**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você.

Comment: Você poderia postar uma screenshot do seu celular durante este erro ?

Comment: rodouo comando `adb -s reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` que pede? deu algum erro ao rodar ele?

Answer (score 4):

Para resolvermos o problema da tela vermelha ao tentarmos dar reload na nossa aplicação devemos fazer o seguinte.
Devemos subir o serviço do node numa porta separada através do comando "`react-native start --port=8088`", porém no momento de configurar o nosso celular temos uma particularidade.

Obs0: **Não feche o terminal que está rodando o seu serviço na nova porta**, para executar os comandos abaixo, abra outra instância do terminal.
Como não temos como apertar nenhuma tecla no celular, devemos enviar o comando "`adb shell input keyevent 82`", isso irá simular o **Ctrl + M** (utilizado para abrir o menu caso você esteja utilizando o emulador do Android Studio) e abrir o menu de opções.

Com o menu aberto, escolha a opção "**Dev Settings**" e depois clique em  "**Debug server host for device**". Agora a particularidade. Execute o comando "`ipconfig`" e recupere o valor do **IPv4**, com esse valor em mãos, escreva o valor do seu IPv4:sua porta (**ex: 123.235.0.13:8088**). Lembrando que a porta deve ser a mesma que foi iniciada pelo comando "**react-native start**". Pronto, com isso feito, seu celular estará apto a realizar o reload utilizando o RR.

Se você estiver usando o emulador, basta seguir os mesmos passos, sem usar os comando "**adb shell input keyevent**" e na hora de inserir o IP, utilize o seguinte IP: 10.0.1.1:[porta_escolhida] ou 10.0.2.2:[porta_escolhida], que no nosso caso foi a porta **8088**, então ficaria: **10.0.1.1:8088** ou **10.0.2.2:8088**

Obs1: Se não funcionar utilizando o ip 10.0.1.1 ou 10.0.2.2, utilize o IPv4 mesmo no emulador.

Obs2: Para simularmos o comando RR basta executar no terminal o comando "`adb shell input keyevent 46 46`".

Obs2.1: Caso ocorra algum erro, tente novamente, as vezes a conexão pode ser perdida.

Obs3: Documentação oficial que me auxiliou na solução: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.32/docs/running-on-device-android.html

Obs4: O celular deve estar conectado na mesma rede wi-fi do computador.

Obs5: Esse problema ocorre com pessoas que já tem sua porta 8081 comprometida por algum serviço, e por algum motivo específico, não o podem parar. (Ex: **McAfee**)

Obs6: Todos os comando citados acima devem ser executados na pasta raiz do seu projeto.

Espero ter ajudado.
Um abraço!